# Unable to refresh data from Excel documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, connection

I have a library in SharePoint Online. When on the library I use the Export to Excel button within the tab.

This downloads the query file which I open, after this I click enable on the security notice to enable content.

This then displays the data from the library. However when I press refresh

[image]

I receive the following error message:
[image]

I am able to export and refresh other libraries in the same manner on the tenancy. I currently have full control access to the data.
When looking at the connection properties they are the same as a user who is currently able to complete the above.

The parent site above the library has recently had a name/url change.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue after changing the site name and url.

The before downloaded query file cannot be refreshed again.

According to my test, it is recommended that you export the file again after the site name/URL is changed.

Comment: Hi Julie, Thanks for the response. I have exported the library to excel after the site name change but unfortunately still the same issue

Comment: Whether other users occur the same issue for this library? Please try to sign out and sign in again with current user then check again.

Comment: I have got the user to sign in and out but unfortunately still the same issue. I am able to perform the refresh myself. But everyone else seems to get the same issue

Comment: Sorry to reply so late, please try to clear the browser cache and test again.

Comment: Just tried to clear the cache and unfortunately still the same issue